# Connect newly drawn lines to existing lines in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, snapping, digitizing

I need a simple tip for drawing line shapes in QGIS. I have multiple line shapes in my project that needs to be connected, so is there an option to join my already drawn line with the line that I'm drawing so they can have same connection point, but without zooming it to the max?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is doing a ***snapping*** operation, which is a very common task in a GIS software.

Simply, go to `Settings >> Snapping Options...` and set where to apply the snapping and a custom tolerance. For example:

[image]

In this way, when you will try to digitize a new point, QGIS will automatically *snap* it to the nearest vertex (from another layer) that is within the tolerance set.

If you need more advanced options (for example, enabling snapping only to specified layer, select `Advanced` from the `Layer selection` box).

Comment: @СтеванСтојиљковић You're welcome, I'm glad you found a solution.

Comment: I prefer to use 10 pixel tolerance instead of any map units.